# rJava "EXTPR_PTR" procedure entry point not found in library

Tags: r, rjava, tabulizer

I'm attempting to install rJava as to use the package tabulizer. My steps so far has been to rund `install.packages("rJava")`, run `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-15.0.1")`, and then run `library(rJava)`. When running the last command I first get a pop-up showing `EXTPTR_PTR Entry Point for procedure not found` (based on my hopeful translation), and then in console:

```
   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
   .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
   call: NULL
   error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
   call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
   error: unable to load shared object 'D:/TidlPic/Eric/Documents/R/win- 
   library/4.0/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll'
```

I have made sure I have the latest version of both the JRE and JDK versions of Java, and that both them and R are the 64bit versions. I've also attempted at pointing the   `Java_Home` path to either one of them, as well ast just `../Java`, and they all return the same error. Any clues on what it is wrong? All help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was accidental breakage introduced by R 4.0.0 or R 4.0.1 which was fixed in R 4.0.2 and R 4.0.3.  Are you by chance running 4.0.1?  Upgrading would help.

The official word from one R Core member is to not use `EXTPTR_PTR` (see *e.g.* [this list email](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Possible-ABI-change-in-R-4-0-1-tt4764335.html#none)). The current CRAN version of `rJava` should also be fine.

So in short: 'current' `rJava` with 'current' `R` should be fine.